# How do you change specific values (like 7) in a column to NA in R?

Tags: r, na

I am working on a project where those that did not know are recorded as 7 in my column and those that refused to answer are recorded as 9.  I am trying to find an easy way to convert all these values to NA.

Comment: Well what kind of data structure do you have?  Please show an example

Comment: I'm looking at an NHANES data set

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple logic to assign NA, as in the following very simple example.

```
column <- c(1,2,1,3,7,7,1,2,9)
column[column %in% c(7,9)] <- NA

> column
[1]  1  2  1  3 NA NA  1  2 NA
```

Basically, you can operate on any column of a data frame using the $ operator. This treats the column as a vector. Using a logical operator on the vector returns a vector of TRUE or FALSE back, which can then be used to select the elements of the vector to change to NA.

I would caution that you might not always want to do that. Using NA instead of values in R can have annoying side effects because any operation against NA generally returns NA.

EDITED TO ADD: Per [Gregor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903061/gregor), I should mention that a data frame allows you to select single columns out of it using the `$` operator. For instance, in data frame `df.example`, if the columns are A, B, and C, then `df.example$A` will extract column A as a vector. In contrast, the `[` operator does not create vector subsets, and is used to select multiple columns of a data frame as a smaller data frame. For instance, given our example data frame,  you could select columns A and B as a different data frame using `df.example[c("A","B")]`. For more guidance, trying running `help('[')` in R.

Comment: Fair point. I'm unfortunately now on mobile so an update may take time.

Comment: @Gregor I've expanded my answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `replace()` function to do this:

```
df <- data.frame(value = c(1, 3, 7, 3, 9, 9, 7, 2))
df$value <- replace(df$value, which(df$value==7 | df$value==9), NA)
```

Result:

```
> df
  value
1     1
2     3
3    NA
4     3
5    NA
6    NA
7    NA
8     2
```

This looks cumbersome, but I've found it convenient in situations where the `which` piece gets messier. Then you do that part on another line and just point this one at the object you created there.